# Zend Framework - Where should we place our custom Validators?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate, custom-validators

We can read here how to write:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html

```
class MyValid_Float extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
```

1)
**Where should we place this?**

application/default/validators ?
application/view/helpers/... ?

2)
**Do we have to register this somewhere on our application ?**

**Update:**
Here's an example of my bootstrap:

```
include_once 'config_root.php';
set_include_path ( $PATH );

require_once 'Initializer.php';
require_once "Zend/Loader.php";
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

// Set up autoload.
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance ();
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader ( true );
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings ( false );

// Prepare the front controller.
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ();
$frontController->throwExceptions(true);
$frontController->registerPlugin ( new Initializer ( PROJECT_ENV ) );

// Dispatch the request using the front controller.
try {
    $frontController->dispatch ();

} catch ( Exception $exp ) {
    $contentType = "text/html";
    header ( "Content-Type: $contentType; charset=UTF-8" );
    echo "an unexpected error occurred.";
    echo "<h2>Unexpected Exception: " . $exp->getMessage () . "</h2><br /><pre>";
    echo $exp->getTraceAsString ();
}
```

SO, do I have to add here:

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
    'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
    'namespace' => '',
));

$resourceLoader->addResourceType('validate', 'validators/', 'My_Validate_');
```

And then I should create a file IN: (note that this configuration is using default module):

*application/default/validators/ValidateSpam.php*

And on validateSpam.php have something like:

```
class My_Validate_Spam extends Zend_Validate_Abstract {
```

Can you please confirm ?

Thanks

Comment: If there's no specific place for creating this class, please tell me where you normally place it. And if you need or not to registered somehow within the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your `application/validators`
then in your application's Bootstrap class, add the following function:

```
protected function _initAutoload () {

        // configure new autoloader
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader (array ('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));

        // autoload validators definition
        $autoloader->addResourceType ('Validator', 'validators', 'Validator_');
}
```

*More detail(s) about [Zend Bootstrap Autoloading](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html)*.

**Another way** is described in [this](http://www.drzycimski.com/programming/zend-framework/no-mvc-zend-framework-zend_forms-decorator-validator-and-filters/) blog, where the constructor of the controller for the form that is using this custom validator has an extra line:

```
class JD_Form_Controller extends Zend_Form
{
 public function __construct($options = null)
 {        
   // path setting for custom classes MUST ALWAYS be first!
   $this->addElementPrefixPath('JD_Form_Validator','JD/Form/Validator','validate');
   ...
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: @Ozair Kafray: And can we just create any path for it ? I mean, can we create a folder inside /Form/ called Validator ? Without Zend to know about ?

Comment: @Ozar Kafray: I'm trying to follow your link instructions (about the accepted answer)and it says: "In order to include files under this folder we need to create an instance of zend resource autoloader" - and my question is: Where should we place that code ? It seems taken for everyone else that that file should be somewhere, that everybody knows about - perhaps I'm missing some information here ?

Comment: Ok, that was a link to give you the concept of Autoloading. I defined auto loading in `_initAutoload ()` function of my Bootstrap class. In this function there is a line for each type of resource such as `$autoloader->addResourceType ('Form', 'forms', 'Form_');`. I will try to paste some code in my answer in a while.

Comment: @Ozair Kafray: I have updated my question, I would just need a confirmation from you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ozair Kafray: I have no class keyword on my bootstrap file, hence, I believe that function will not work. :( But perhaps the way I did on my example could work, I just notice that you have Module_Autoloader and NOT Module_Autoloader_Resource ... perhaps I could change that.

Comment: Yes, my bootstrap class is defined like this `class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap`

Comment: @ozair Kafray - This will be a long comment thing, so I end accepting your answer. I still have an issue, and I've passed to a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442852/zend-honey-pot-validation  - About that class, all the application is working without that class declaration and I'm not sure if I just can add. I would prefer to implement this without to many changes on the application configuration (that I haven't made. :s)

Answer (score 1):

I do it by adding the following line to application.ini :-

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "App_"
```

Then I put my custom validators in (for example) /library/App/Validate/MyCustomValidator.php.

I can then write my validator using something like:-

```
class App_Validate_MyCustomValidator() extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
```

It works pretty well for me and is simple and easy to implement.

Comment: and is you namespace "App_" associated with your folder App in /library/App/ somehow ?

Comment: Yes, Zend looks after that itself ,to use the validator I would do something like myValidator = new App_Validate_MyCustomValidator(). The line added to application.ini above tells autoloader where to find my App_ namespace.